# Let $\phi: I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a convex function. Show $\phi$ is $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)_I$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $I \subset \mathbb R$ be an interval and $\phi: I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a convex function. Show $\phi$ is $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)_I$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable.

I know that if $\phi$ is continuous between $I$ and $\mathbb R$ then it is $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)_I$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable.

I have a theorem saying that $\phi$ is continuous at every point $x \in I^{\circ}$ (interior of $I$).

However, how can I verify if $\phi$ is also continuous at boundary points ?

Comment: You don't need to.

Comment: Why not, please give me a reason.

Answer (score 1):

For $\varphi$ to be measurable, you only need to verify $\varphi^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ is Borel for every $a\in\mathbb R$. Can you see how convexity implies that?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** what is the measure of the boundary of $I$?